# Can you have <param> type tags within a asp.NET WebUserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to create a WebUserControl (not a custom control) in asp.NET (C#).
I want to have `<param>` tags that can be put between the control's start/end tags when being used in an aspx page.

Eg:

```
<abc:myWebUserControl id="myWUC" runat="server">
    <param name="pName1" value="pValue1">
    <param name="pName2" value="pValue2">
    <param name="pName3" value="pValue3">
</abc:myWebUserControl>
```

Can this be done? and how do you do it, how do you read the param data?

Thanks a bunch for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is only available on a Custom server control...

Here is a how to article:

http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/32182/1763/page/1